# Storing two guids in data table

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

I can't find any answer for that, so maybe someone of you will know more about it.
I have a Database with 2 Datatables: Order and Buyer.

```
public partial class Order
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "ID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources_EN))]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "OrderBuyer", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources_EN))]
        public Guid OrderBuyer { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Buyer
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "ID", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources_EN))]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
    }
```

The OrderBuyer in Order is storing Buyer ID key. Is this solution a good implementation?
One Buyer can has multiple Order items which key is also guid. I didn't want to use integers, because of security problems. Maybe there is a better way to do such a thing?

Comment: Well main question is: Is it a good way to store 2 guids in same table? I know that there is very little chance to duplicate it, but generating guid for new Order items will use out guids faster.

Comment: Don't worry about duplicating guids. There are more possible guids than atoms in the universe.

Comment: So reasumming: I can easily use two guids in the same datatable and it's a good practice to do so?

Comment: You can. I have no opinion about good or bad. How should I judge that with this bit of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok.

Since the GUID are not going to be used for the same purpose :

One is the ID of the table, and the other one is the ID of the buyer, for what i can see in your question, your logic is good.